# Basic crossbrowser stylesheet template

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I was always using frameworks or ready-to-use boilerplates for apps development (ReactJS mostly). Right now I'm building a simple static website (using Hugo generator). I don't want to use any kind of big-ish CSS frameworks. However, I wouldn't like to reinvent a wheel by building it completely from scratch. Is there any kind of conventional solutions for this? May be some kind of tiny css-framework or a normalizer etc?

I am not asking for a specific library - I'm asking what should I look for IN the first place: framework, compiler, normalizer etc.

Comment: What did you mean with "conventional solution"? Do you want a UI framework like the twitter boostrap? Or do you want something more simple like a reset css?

Comment: probably, i want a framework, that will set initial things like global css props and maybe grid. But i definitely don't need any kind of predefined buttons or whatever else ui elements

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know if I understood completely what you want, but, I think this can help you.

[This is a list](https://www.keycdn.com/blog/front-end-frameworks/) of the top UI frameworks of 2016/2017.

My favorites are:

- [Semantic-UI](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjM36CRvu3TAhXJHJAKHVECAk0QFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fsemantic-ui.com%2F&usg=AFQjCNGym7_5ZVBUiUUoqYNtzlsI35nyoQ&sig2=w8Mv5uUEJvaNBBD_4AJAqw)
- [Material-UI](http://www.material-ui.com/)

There are more simple solutions like [Pure](http://purecss.io/).

Recently I used Material-UI to build this [React Application](https://github.com/darde/RD-Book-Store).